# Changing CSS opacity in hover event is not working

Tags: jquery, css, animation, mouseover

I have a set of buttons. When the mouse hovers over one of them, the others will be partially faded out with a jQuery animation.

As long as the mouse stays within a 30px boundary from the buttons (vertically), they will remain with an opacity of 60% (except for the one the mouse is at). If it hovers over another button within the boundary, such will gain 100% opacity and the previous one will turn to 60%, and if it leaves the 30px boundary all buttons will restore to 100% opacity. This behavior is given by the following JavaScript code:

```
var q3my;

$("#q3ans div").hover(function(e){
    q3my = e.screenY;
    $(this).css({opacity:1});
    $("#q3ans div").not(this).animate({opacity:0.6},200);      
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(q3my && Math.abs(e.screenY-q3my)>30){
        $("#q3ans div").animate({opacity:1},100);
        q3my=0 
    }
});
```

Where all buttons are wrapped inside `#q3ans`. Additionally, `q3my` is utilized to keep record of the y-coordinate where the hover event is fired in order to determine when to restore opacity to the buttons.

The HTML is the following:

```
<div id="q3ans">
    <!--Button 1-->
    <div class="qanswer" id="q3a1">
        <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
    <!--Button n-->
    <div class="qanswer" id="q3an">
        <span>n</span>
    </div>       
</div>
```

The problem is that, after hovering over one button, when the mouse hovers over another button and *doesn't* leave the 30px boundary, the new button remains with 60% (0.6) opacity, rather than 100% (1).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/z6pZy/1/) illustrating problem.

I found a way to *partially* fix the issue, replacing `$(this).css({opacity:1});` with `$(this).animate({opacity:1},0);`, but this causes an awkward delay that feels rough. I might have to use this solution, but if you have another way to solve this it would be great.

**Edit:** it also works when hovering twice on the second button for some reason.

Comment: I believe the problem is the `animate` in the mousemove is fighting the direct CSS assignment.

Comment: @user2864740: maybe, but that animate shouldn't be executed *unless* the mouse is >30px away from the buttons.

Comment: Any already-running running animation won't stop itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure when you animate to `stop()` all previous animations.

```
var q3my;

$("#q3ans div").hover(function(e){
    q3my = e.screenY;
    $(this).stop().css({opacity:1});
    $("#q3ans div").not(this).animate({opacity:0.6},200);      
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(q3my && Math.abs(e.screenY-q3my)>30){
        $("#q3ans div").animate({opacity:1},100);
        q3my=0 
    }
});
```

It looks like the buttons are remaining 60% because they have a stale animation going on.

Comment: Actually, you didn't solve the issue, *but* I was able to solve it using `.stop()` right before the `.css` rather than the animations. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Thanks. Here, a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/z6pZy/2/) for reference.